# Retrieve hidden text blocks and replace all content between two of them

Tags: c#, openxml

I want to use OpenXML to automate Word document creation by taking a given document as a template. This template contains text blocks with a special syntax (namely e.g. `«tagname[»`...`«]tagname»`) in the form of hidden text (in the font dialog box, the 'Hidden' checkbox in the effects section is activated) so that they don't show up when the document is printed.

Depending on the `tagname` I want to replace any content which might be already there in the template file between the opening and closing tag with some other content (e.g. in `«today[»01/01/2000«]today»` the content `01/01/2000` would be substituted with `07/06/2018`) preferably preserving the format (e.g. bold, italic or text color).

How can I retrieve the hidden text parts and is there an easy way to replace anything between corresponding tags using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly are the text blocks in your template. Instead you can use Content Control from Developer options at the required place, then you can name them from the properties of content control.

[image]

**today** will be name of the Content Control

Once you have all the content control at your template, you can look for specific content control with name and add the new value you want to.

Here is the Snippet to give you an idea.

```
   // Title is name of content control(today), value is what you want to add(1/01/2000)

  private static void UpdateControl(WordprocessingDocument document, string title, string value)
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
        var sdtRuns = mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtRun>()
        .Where(run => run.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value == title);

        foreach (SdtRun sdtRun in sdtRuns)
        {
            sdtRun.Descendants<Text>().First().Text = value;
        }

        document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
```